# A libcurl function was given a bad argument

Tags: macos, curl, macos-sierra

I have previously been able to upload .ipa files to the HockeyApp site, via their REST API (https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-apps#upload-app).

Now, when I attempt to upload:

```
curl -F "status=2" -F "notify=1" -F "notes=Testing." -F "notes_type=0" -F "ipa=@hockeyapp.ipa" -H "X-HockeyAppToken: [Token, removed]" https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/upload
```

I get:

```
curl: (43) A libcurl function was given a bad argument"
```

The file `hockeyapp.ipa` is present in the current working directory.

I am on Mac OS X Sierra Version 10.12.3.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out the file hockeyapp.ipa was actually a directory containing the actual .ipa file.

Comment: hey I stuck here, can you write the descriptive answer, coudn't understand it.

Comment: If I remember correctly - it has been a while, the file I thought was an .ipa was actually a directory I had mistakenly called hockeyapp.ipa.. which was silly of me.